# Exporting to pdf - Reporting Viewer

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, pdf, reportviewer

I created a report in Report Viewer using the source 3 of 9 barcode, (for bar code), put the font in the Fonts folder in Windows. But the export to PDF the font does not appear, but now when I export to excel is perfect.

Does anyone have any idea what can be?

I'm using VS2008 - MVC - LINQ and C # language.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK ReportViewer does not embed font in the output pdf.
You could try to "post process" the resulting pdf and try to include the fonts using Ghostscript.